# Selenium GDPR NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

I want to scrape some data from "https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/review/wearable-tech/". I figured out that looping through the pages with Beautifulsoup does not work. This is the reason why I tried to open it with selenium. The "Accept All" Button to overcome the GDPR blocker cannot be located.

I tried:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/review/wearable-tech/")
# button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[5]/button[2]')
# WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "html/body/div/div[3]/div[5]/button[2]"))).click()
```

I always receive NoSuchElementException

To be honest, I found the Xpath really weird, but I got this from the Google Chrome inspect.

Every solution proposal or tip is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on `Accept All` button which is inside an `iframe`.You need to switch to `iframe` first in order to click the button.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and use the following css selector.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use the following xpath selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/review/wearable-tech/")
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old,
but i would like provide my own solution!
First step is to recognize the "id" of the form that you are actually view, and then you need to move the focus on it!

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gdpr-consent-notice"]'))

    cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-theme/div/div/app-notice/app-theme/div/div/app-home/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[3]/span')

    cookies.click()
```